# How to ignore TqdmExperimentalWarning?

Tags: python, python-3.x, suppress-warnings, tqdm

Everytime a `tqdm_gui` object is created, a warning is printed. I tried to suppress it with `contextlib` but to no avail.

```py
import contextlib as ctx
from tqdm import TqdmExperimentalWarning
from tqdm.gui import tqdm_gui

total = 0

with ctx.suppress(TqdmExperimentalWarning):
    for i in tqdm_gui(range(100_000_000)):
        total += i

print(total)
```

Output:

```
main.py:8: TqdmExperimentalWarning: GUI is experimental/alpha
  for i in tqdm_gui(range(100_000_000))
```

How do I get rid of the warning?

Answer (score 1):

```
import warnings
from tqdm import TqdmExperimentalWarning

warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=TqdmExperimentalWarning)
```